# Toolbar custom icon reset after switching between navigation drawer items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-toolbar, android-architecture-navigation

So I am using latest NavigationView for navigation drawer along with custom toolbar icon. When I launch my app, I can see my custom icon in the toolbar(Actionbar) but as soon as I switch to different fragment by clicking on Menu item in navigation Drawer, my toolbar reset back to hambuger icon and it never sets my custom icon back no matter how many times I toggle between the NavigationDrawer item. Below it my code -

```
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);


        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_score, R.id.nav_history,
                R.id.nav_setting)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();


        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_custom_icon);//your icon here
```

Additional information if require ...

1. I am using new material dependency 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
2. My base application theme is  style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"

I changed the order of the above code to see it there is anything that I have got wrong (it was suggested in some [old stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48018255/3789164)).

Comment: Why are you even using `setupActionBarWithNavController` if you don't want the icon to automatically change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an [expected result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer).

> When using `NavigationUI`, the top app bar helpers automatically transition between the drawer icon and the Up icon as the current destination changes

You can add the `OnDestinationChangedListener` to set your own icons after your setup method.

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_xxx){
                    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable....);
                }
            }
        });
```