# android change Hamburger icon of Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've seen almost all the links related to it but they were not implemented according to my requirement.  I want to replace this default icon with my custom drawer icon. So that's why I've to ask question here. Help me to change hamburger icon. Thanks!

Here is my code for Navigation Drawer.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
ImageView backButton;
DrawerLayout drawer;
NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    backButton = header.findViewById(R.id.back);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });

    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
            .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
            .build();


    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change hamburger icon in Android (NavigationDrawer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473404/how-to-change-hamburger-icon-in-android-navigationdrawer)

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.dashboardicon);//your icon here
```

try this

Comment: I've already tried this but icon doesn't show