# How do I change the icon of the navigation drawer from the hamburger icon to something else?

Tags: java, android

I've tried doing this but it doesn't work, because I'm still seeing the original hamburger icon:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu_icon);
        toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu_icon);
```

What can I do to fix this? Another thing is that I'm using this `@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow` so is that obstructing the icon from showing up?

Comment: Please check the solutions - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473404/how-to-change-hamburger-icon-in-android-navigationdrawer)

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but it doesn't work either.